# Android widgets overlapping

Tags: android, layout, widget

This is screenshot of my app. The xml file has textview and edittexts. Its working fine on my device but when I test the same app on other devices its overlapping. What should I change? Below is my xml code. And here are the screenshots tested on 2 devices.I have added the entire xml code. Any help appreciated. 
 [image]
 [image]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#E3F2FD"
tools:context=".DataSheet1">
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/shift"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edit"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/date"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-36dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/crop_day"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Shift"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edit"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edit"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Crop Day"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crop_day"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edit"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="141dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Crushing Day"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/crushing_day"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edit"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="198dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Shift A"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/shift_a"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-198dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edit"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="129dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Shift B"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/shift_b"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-129dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edit"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Shift C"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/shift_c"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/shift_b"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edit"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Today"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/today"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-49dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edit"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:text="Todate"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/todate"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/today"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_text_edit"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="224dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:text="Shift-wise cane crushing information for current date"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The `and more widgets` section is important - please include your complete layout file in your question

Comment: @ PPartisan - I have updated

Comment: Don't use a `FrameLayout` - it isn't designed for this use case. Use something like a `LinearLayout` (or `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`, but `LinearLayout` will probably be simplest for you to use)

Comment: @PPartisan - I had put a swipe tab so used frameLayout. Will try with RelativeLayout

Comment: @ PPartisan - I tried using Relative Layout but widgets are still overlapping when device size changes

Comment: Your widgets wont overlap if their positions are defined relative to each other. Try using a `LinearLayout`

Comment: @ PPartisan- could u give me an example?

Comment: https://abhiandroid.com/ui/linear-layout